# Import Data to Realm Database

Tags: ios, json, swift, csv, realm

I want to use a centralized database and am looking at various options to do so. From my understanding, I have three main options: SQLite, Realm, and CoreData. Are these options fine for a large centralized database for all users.

Additionally, I am trying to import data from JSON and CSV into a Realm database. Does Realm have this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

As for now Realm does not seem to have the import functionality that you need. Check this [thread](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues/34) for more information.

Realm does have a great documentation that you can read at [Realm](https://realm.io/) and for SQLite there is [this](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) framework (there are for sure more out there) and they both support Swift 2.x. You have to check what suits your requests most.

I can also recommend you to read [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2e3iwe/what_database_to_use/) database thread at reddit.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String composeJsonFromRealm(){
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
        wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
       // Build the query looking at all users:
        // Execute the query:
        RealmResults<User> users = realm.where(User.class).findAll();

        if (users.size()>0){
                User user = users.first();
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("name", user.getName());
                map.put("email",user.getEmail());
                wordList.add(map);


        }

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        return gson.toJson(wordList);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to import data from JSON and CSV into a Realm database. Does Realm have this functionality?

With [Realm Cocoa Converter](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa-converter) you can import CSV, XLSX, and JSON, and export CSV data. Though, at the moment, it only supports OS X.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Realm Studio does have the import functionality from CSV.

Open the Realm Studio, *File -> Create Realm from -> CSV*

[image]

Cheers,

Murat