# Enable user to import/export to Realm database?

Tags: realm

Is there currently a way to allow the user to import/export data to/from the Realm database inside the iOS environment? (ie: when the user is running the application on their phone on the real world, as opposed to preloading data during development)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Data to Realm Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362618/import-data-to-realm-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Realm Cocoa Converter](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa-converter) allows to import data from CSV and XLSX and export data to CSV. This is a framework, which allows you to do such conversions programmatically. <del>The Realm Browser for OS X is supporting that [in the future](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues/34) via a user-interface.</del>
**Update:** The Realm Browser for OS X supports that from the menu via "File > Import From" / "File > Export To".

Comment: Thanks marius - I see how I can use the Realm Cocoa Converter as a Swift script from OS X, but its unclear how I can do utilise it from inside my iOS app? [Of course this could just reflect my complete lack of experience, forgive me... :) ]

Comment: Okay, I think now I understand what you are actually trying to achieve. I don't think now, that this is the right tool for the job. Realm Cocoa Converter deals with unstructured data and creates the necessary schema itself. You want to make probably stronger expectations and so you'll be likely better off building the functionality yourself for a given schema. But feel free to look a round in the code base and see how it is done for the generic case, as there might be still lot to learn and adapt for your concrete problem.

Comment: I missed that the browser already exposes this functionality via the menu. Updated my answer regarding that.

Comment: Thanks marius, much appreciated!